# Why is Instagram block my Python Selenuim code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was trying to make a tool to follow my account and automate that with Selenuim but when I start this code the Instagram give me this

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('instagram.com/mariam_anabosi/') #i deleted https beacuse discord will delete it
time.sleep(10)
```

the web:
[image]

Comment: Instagram is blocking your code because it is detecting a bot, which [it likely doesn't allow](https://www.instagram.com/robots.txt). Seems like your specific example is also a private account